# Radius of curvature and continuous functions

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Let $\kappa (x)$ be radius of curvature function for a continuous function $f(x)$.

Is it necessary that $\kappa(x)$ will have extrema when $f(x)$ does. And the nature of extrema is opposite to that of $f(x)$

$ $

That means If $f(x)$ has maxima, then $\kappa (x)$ has a minima.

$ $

Following link contains a graph :

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ps9wp1ykzm

$f(x)$ is the black curve.

If you know any other noteworthy property about $\kappa(x)$ do point out. I am trying to understand $\kappa(x)$ functions.

Comment: What is $\kappa(x)$?

Comment: I mentioned in the heading

Comment: Took the liberty of transporting that information to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You say "radius of curvature", but the expression reported in the link is based on the "curvature" that is $1/R$.
The formula for the (signed) curvature is 
$$
\kappa(x)=\frac{f''(x)}{\{1+[f'(x)]^2\}^{3/2}}
$$
so that
$$
\kappa'(x)=\frac{f'''(x)\{1+[f'(x)]^2\}-3f'(x)[f''(x)]^2}{\{1+[f'(x)]^2\}^{5/2}}
$$
and as you can see it does not vanish, in general, when $f'(x)=0$.

Also in your case, $f'(x)=0$ in $0$ and $\pm 1$, while $\kappa'(x)=0$ in $0$ and in two point $x\approx\pm1.01444$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a curve whose radius of curvature increases monotonically as you move along it, such as a logarithmic spiral.

Orient it such that it is horizontal at some point $P$.

In some neighborhood of $P$ the curve will be the graph of a function.

This function has an extremum at $P$, but (by our initial choice) its radius of curvature keeps increasing past $P$, and so in particular doesn't have an extremum there.